# PSPDFKit note annotation issue with toolbar

Tags: ios, pspdfkit

I am trying PSDFKit demo version to display pdf files in my application. I have added PSPDFViewcontroller as child view to app view hierarchy.And PSPDKIt toolbars are hidden.App is using toolbars of parent view controller.

My problem is that when I tried to add note annotation then it gets overlapped with bottom toolbar.
Could not find reason behind this strange behaviour.

What could be reason?
Here is my code

```
-(void)showDocumentWithFileURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSData*pdfdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    PSPDFDocument *document = [PSPDFDocument documentWithData:pdfdata];
    [document.outlineParser outline];    //Parse outline..
    self.psPdfViewController = [[PSPDFViewController alloc] initWithDocument:document];
    self.psPdfViewController.scrollingEnabled = YES;
    self.psPdfViewController.toolbarEnabled = NO;
    self.psPdfViewController.delegate = self;
    self.psPdfViewController.document.delegate = self;
    self.psPdfViewController.shouldHideStatusBarWithHUD = NO;
    self.psPdfViewController.renderAnimationEnabled = NO;
    self.psPdfViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed =YES;
    //Hide bottom page scrollbar.

    self.psPdfViewController.scrollDirection = PSPDFScrollDirectionVertical;
    self.psPdfViewController.leftBarButtonItems = @[];

    //Add pspdf view as chaild view controller.
    [self addChildViewController:self.psPdfViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.psPdfViewController.view];
    //Add Navigation Bar and toolbar Buttons.
    [self updateHeaderFooter];
 }
else
  {
    [self updateHeaderFooter];
  }
```

}